# How to disable sound effects at Ubuntu startup?

Tags: ubuntu, audio

Ubuntu plays a couple of sound files at its startup. These sound effects become annoying when one is in a meeting where such noise distracts everyone else. What is the easiest way to disable the two sound files that are played when Ubuntu boots and the user logs in? Is there a way to automatically mute the system volume at the startup?

Comment: Request: please move this question to AskUbuntu.

Comment: When I asked this question, askubuntu didn't exist. I think it makes sense to move to askubuntu now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the configuration in two places to disable the log on sound and mute the system at startup.

Go to "Preferences -> Sound", select the "Sounds" tab and make sure the log on sound effect is disabled.

To make the system volume mute at startup, add the following command to the startup programs.

> amixer set 'Master' mute

You can add to the list of startup programs by selecting the following menu item:

> System -> Preferences -> Startup
>   Applications

Answer (score 5):

In Ubuntu 10.04 you can go to System > Preferences > Startup Applications

In the program list look for 'GNOME Login Sound' and uncheck it.

Then the 'drum sound' is disabled by going to System > Administration > Login Screen and unchecking 'Play Login Sound'

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo bash
cd /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/
mv system-ready.ogg SHUT_UP_WHEN_READY__THANK_YOU.orz
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the gnome schema xml config:-

sudo vi /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.unity-greeter.gschema.xml

Find the setting "play-ready-sound" and change the setting from true to false. 
Save the xml file

Regenerate the config to take the new setting:-
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/

Restart the PC and the sound will be gone.

Answer (score -2):

you could just disable all sounds in system > preferences > sound. select sound profile: none